# spark 2.3 read hive table is always 0 rows

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a question about the `spark` read hive table this week we update spark from 1.5 to 2.3. We have a lot of tables, Its data is inserted using `spark 1.5`.  Now `Spark 2.3` cannot read table data, No error but can not found data, always 0 rows. I used `sparksession.read.orc("/hive/table/path")` ,It works.

Spark config :

```
spark.sql.orc.impl = hive
spark.sql.orc.enableVectorizedReader = true
spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc = true
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: can you show one table create statement ?

Comment: use Spark 1.5  ```df.write.format("orc").saveAsTable("db.xxtable")```  'df' read from other hive table